# The return value of open("dev/null",O_APPEND) can indicate too many files opened?

Tags: c++, linux, networking, boost

I can't understand the codes below. when reservedFd_ == -2, it indicate that there are two many clients accepted, why? Thank you very much.

```
// In one function.
...
...
reservedFd_ = ::open("/dev/null", O_APPEND);
if (-1 == reservedFd_)
{
    LOG_DEBUG("Failed to open reserved file!, errno: %d", errno);
}

...
...
...
----------------------------------------------------------------------
// then in other function we accept a new client socket
void TCPServer::HandleAccept( const boost::system::error_code& _err )
{
    if (!_err)
    {
            // too many clients accepted? why?
        if (-2 == reservedFd_)
        {
            boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
            session_->GetSocket().close(ignored_ec);
        }
        else
        {
        ...
        }

    }

...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`open(2)` returns a new file descriptor, or -1 if an error occurred. `errno` will tell you the specific cause of failure. If there are too many file descriptors open then you should get EMFILE or ENFILE. Use `strerror(3)` to get a readable error message.

```
LOG_DEBUG("Failed to open reserved file: %s", strerror(errno));
```

`open(2)` should never return -2. That would be an undocumented return code that violates the POSIX.1 specification. It would cause problems with the huge number of programs in the world that aren't expecting it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Maybe I didn't describe it clearly. ::open("/dev/null", O_APPEND) and if (-2 == reservedFd_) are not in the same function. Is it possible that after open /dev/null success, the value reservedFd_ was modified by system at other place?For the reason that process has accepted too many client socket?